# Organize database for online curses

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I'm charged to create a website, where the administrator can add new chapter, articles titles and subtitles (and maybe sub subtitles...etc),

I've thought of creating parent-child tables:

> 1-Curse(N_curse,title,intro,date)
>   2-chapter
>   (N_chapter,N_curse,Title,intro) (where
>   curse is parent of chapter)
>   3-title(N_title,N_chapter,intro,text)
>   (where title is chapter's child)
>   4-subtitle(N_subtitle,N_chapter,intro,text)
>   (where subtitle is title'child) 
> 5-...

and so on.

But I think that this is not a practical whay to define a such n-tree database, so what's the solution to respect open use for every subtitle added by the administrator??? thank you

Comment: See: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html

Comment: @omg ponies, I really appriciate...thanks :-) +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm a pretty hard-core relational guy, and I'd say that the newer "noSQL" databases may make this much easier.  The dividing line seems to be if your system is more document-oriented or transaction-oriented, and if it is going to have many more reads than writes (sounds like it).

Take a look at the MongoDB tutorials, they may give you some ideas.